# Activiti Api processInstanceIds(processInstanceIds)

Tags: activiti

is it possible to make a request to act_hi_varinst with a list of processInstanceId.
in the current api i can do this: historyService.createHistoricVariableInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId) but i can't find this: historyService.createHistoricVariableInstanceQuery().processInstanceIds(processInstanceIds). So is there any other alternatives to make this request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I known you can't achieve this by using **HistoricVariableInstanceQueryImpl**.
You should use **NativeHistoricVariableInstanceQueryImpl**.
e.g.,

```
historyService.createNativeHistoricVariableInstanceQuery().sql("select
* from ACT_HI_VARINST where PROC_INST_ID_ IN ('1', '2')");
```